# Easy way to store Java objects to MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, database

Let's say I have this kind of Java object:

```
String brand = "Toyota";
String model = "Corolla";
int year = "2013";

CarBean car = new CarBean(brand, model, year);
```

How to store easily this object to MySQL? I've done JDBC succefully and tables are working, but there is always something that gives me grey hairs.

What would be easy (but at least semi professional) way to store/retrieve data back and forth with NetBeans and MySQL?

Comment: Netbeans has nothing to do with it. What is it that _gives [you] grey hairs_?

Answer (score 9):

One common approach to this would be to use an object/relational mapping (ORM) framework, such as [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/).

Then you can use annotations (either Hibernate annotations or JPA annotations) to accomplish the mapping. The full details are too involved for a StackOverflow answer, but for your example it's pretty straightforward:

```
package myapp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {
    private Long id;
    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private Integer year;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    @Column(name = "brand")
    public String getBrand() { return brand; }

    public void setBrand(String brand) { this.brand = brand; }

    @Column(name = "model")
    public String getModel() { return model; }

    public void setModel(String model) { this.model = model; }

    @Column(name = "year")
    public Integer getYear() { return year; }

    public void setYear(Integer year) { this.year = year; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a table in your database, for example named `Cars`, that has the appropriate format to fit your domain class, `CarBean`. Then use a `PreparedStatement` to insert rows.

```
Connection con = ... // get a connection
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Cars (brand, model, year) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
ps.setString(1, carBean.getBrand());
ps.setString(2, carBean.getModel());
ps.setInt(3, carBean.getYear());
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Don't forget to close the `PreparedStatement` somewhere down the line.

You can again use the `PreparedStatement` to retrieve rows.

Answer (score 4):

The term you are looking for is Object-relational mapping [Object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)  (ORM or sometimes referred to as O/R Mapping) It maps your Plain old java code to any to RDBMS table.

An Example from Hibernate,

You have this POJO.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "car")
    public class Car {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        @Column
        private String brand;
        @Column
        private String model;

        public Long getId() { return id; }

        public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

        public String getBrand() { return brand; }

        public void setBrand(String brand) { this.brand = brand; }

        public String getModel() { return model; }

        public void setModel(String model) { this.model = model; }

    }
```

Now to Persist this with Hibernate all we have to do is .

```
Car car = new Car();
car.setBrand("BRAND");
car.setModel("MODEL");
session.save(car);
```

Please note that I'd remove some code to simplify the example